# Jade database and PHP

Tags: php, jade-platform

I have software written in Jade. The data stored in it is something like a components list. I would like to have a web page with select options which would select data from the Jade software/database and display it on that page.

I have some experience with PHP and I did a simple app in Jade (something like a library system they have as an example/tutorial on Jade website).

Mine knowledge is not enough to answer this question - can Jade and PHP work together like PHP + MySQL? If no - what can I use to pass data from Jade to PHP. If yes - what do I need to learn to make it work?

Comment: I haven't finished googling yet.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, JADE can work together with PHP like MySQL. You can do this via JADE's ODBC driver.

For more details on how to do this, see https://secure.jadeworld.com/downloads/jade/papers/JADE_WP_RelationalQueriesUsingODBC.pdf for details on the JADE ODBC driver, and http://php.net/manual/en/book.uodbc.php for details on PHP's ODBC functions.

Answer (score -1):

It seems you're mixing up some terms here. Jade is a templating engine. You can put data into it and Jade will return HTML code. It serves as a View in the MVC pattern. Your Model then would be the MySQL database. Your PHP code acts as a controller, responsible of getting data from the Model and putting it into the View.

Jade was originally written by TJ Holowaychuk for Node.js. There are several ports to other languages (like PHP). They're all on different levels of completeness and active development.

I suggest using Google for a search like "GitHub Jade PHP".

If you find no libary that suits your needs, you can still look for other templating languages, like HAML for example. Again, Google will help you: "PHP templating languages".

I presume that you have enough experience to load results from a MySQL database and pass them to an instance of a class, so I'm not gonna cover this here. If not, please ask a new question.

Comment: We are not. But your tag "jade" reads "High performance templating engine heavily influenced by Haml", so technically speaking my answer is correct.

However, see my comment on your question.